# How to UPDATE just one record in DB2?

Tags: mysql, database, transactions, db2

In **DB2**, I need to do a [`SELECT FROM UPDATE`](http://db2portal.blogspot.com/2007/04/select-from-delete-update-and-merge-db2.html), to put an update + select in a single transaction.
But I need to make sure to *update only one record* per transaction.

Familiar with the `LIMIT` clause from [MySQL's `UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html) option

> places a limit on the number of rows that can be updated

I looked for something similar in [DB2's `UPDATE` reference](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0001022.html) but without success.

How can something similar be achieved in DB2?

---

*Edit:* In my scenario, I have to deliver 1000 coupon codes upon request. I just need to select (any)one that has not been given yet.

Comment: Why don't you add a `WHERE` condition containing the primary key of the row to be updated?

Comment: I too would be suspicious of updating (what is essentially) a _random_, individual row, and getting it

Comment: In my scenario, I have to deliver 1k coupon codes upon request, so I just need to select one that has not been given yet.

Comment: Could you just generate it on-the-fly?  Define a stored procedure that'll insert it into the table, and return it to the query?  Otherwise, the version of DB2 I'm on (iSeries V6R1) doesn't support `UPDATE` statements for data-change references (only `INSERT`), which could be easily geared to only getting one row... Or, what about having the update select the `MAX()` or `MIN()` unclaimed coupon (potential concurrency issues, there)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question uses some ambiguous terminology that makes it unclear what needs to be accomplished. Fortunately, DB2 offers robust support for a variety of SQL patterns.

To limit the number of rows that are modified by an `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE 
( SELECT t.column1 FROM someschema.sometable t WHERE ... FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY
) 
SET column1 = 'newvalue';
```

The `UPDATE` statement never sees the base table, just the expression that filters it, so you can control which rows are updated.

---

To `INSERT` a limited number of new rows:

```
INSERT INTO mktg.offeredcoupons( cust_id, coupon_id, offered_on, expires_on )
SELECT c.cust_id, 1234, CURRENT TIMESTAMP, CURRENT TIMESTAMP + 30 DAYS 
FROM mktg.customers c 
LEFT OUTER JOIN mktg.offered_coupons o
ON o.cust_id = c.cust_id
WHERE ....
AND o.cust_id IS NULL
FETCH FIRST 1000 ROWS ONLY;
```

---

This is how DB2 supports `SELECT` from an `UPDATE`, `INSERT`, or `DELETE` statement:

```
SELECT column1 FROM NEW TABLE (
    UPDATE ( SELECT column1 FROM someschema.sometable 
             WHERE ... FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY
    ) 
    SET column1 = 'newvalue'
) AS x;
```

The `SELECT` will return data from only the modified rows.

Comment: For DB2, in the first code block, the part `SET t.column1 = 'newvalue'` should actually be `SET column1 = 'newvalue'` because the alias `t` is not scoped outside the subquery. *PS: I didn't know such an update is even possible! Kudos!*

Comment: Good catch, @ADTC. I've corrected that code sample.

Answer (score 2):

You have two options.  As noted by [A Horse With No Name](https://stackoverflow.com/users/330315/a-horse-with-no-name), you can use the primary key of the table to ensure that one row is updated at a time.

The alternative, if you're using a programming language and have control over cursors, is to use a cursor with the 'FOR UPDATE' option (though that may be probably optional; IIRC, cursors are 'FOR UPDATE' by default when the underlying SELECT means it can be), and then use an UPDATE statement with the `WHERE CURRENT OF <cursor-name>` in the UPDATE statement.  This will update the one row currently addressed by the cursor.  The details of the syntax vary with the language you're using, but the raw SQL looks like:

```
DECLARE CURSOR cursor_name FOR
    SELECT *
      FROM SomeTable
     WHERE PKCol1 = ? AND PKCol2 = ?
       FOR UPDATE;

UPDATE SomeTable
   SET ...
 WHERE CURRENT OF cursor_name;
```

If you can't write DECLARE in your host language, you have to do manual bashing to find the equivalent mechanism.

Comment: Please note that this won't work as expected if your cusor was defined to take advantage of blocking (returning a whole set of rows) - it will update only the _last_ row in the current block (because of the row-pointer position).

Comment: Thanks, @X-Zero; I wasn't even aware that there was a way to break 'WHERE CURRENT OF'; it is amazing what options there are.  It isn't a dreadfully good way of doing things; I prefer to update a record by searching on the primary key, even though that is 'slower' than techniques such as WHERE CURRENT OF.