# SQL statement to update key field

Tags: sql, db2

I have two tables,  pinfo and address

**pinfo:**

> ```
> pnumber  varchar 
> myunikey INTEGER (unikey)
> systemid integer
> ```

**address:**

> ```
> amyPinfoKey  INTEGER (new row with NULL val) 
> anumber varchar (connects to to pinfo.pnumber)
> ```

(Not all the rows connect to the pinfo table - some rows have no connection at all)

I'm trying to run a SQL command that will set `address.amyPinfoKey` = `pinfo.myunikey` only where `address.anumber` = `pinfo.pnumber`

The tricky part is that `pinfo.pnumber` can be duplicated so I need only one of the matches on `pinfo.myunikey` (it doesn't matter which one)

I'm using a DB2 database

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to UPDATE just one record in DB2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8735428/how-to-update-just-one-record-in-db2)

Comment: thank you... it's answer my question

Answer (score 0):

```
UDATE address
 SET    address.amyPinfoKey = (SELECT myunikey  = (SELECT myunikey
                          FROM   (SELECT MAX(myunikey) AS myunikeyMax,
                                         pnumber       AS pnumberMax
                                  FROM   pinfo
                                  GROUP  BY pinfo.pnumber) AS pinfoMax,
                                 pinfo
                          WHERE  pinfoMax.pnumberMax = pinfo.pnumber
                                 AND pinfoMax.myunikeyMax = pinfo.myunikey
                                 AND address.anumber = pinfo.pnumber)
```

Hope that can help you ,that's a distincy question.
And there is some typical update statements

```
update tableA set tableA.ColA = (
                                   select tableB.colA
                                   from tableB
                                   where tableB.id = tableA.id
                                 --  and some other conditon 
                                )
where condition
```

and like this:

```
update (select tableA.colA,tableB.colA newA
        from tableA,tableB
        where tableA.id = tableB.id

    )
set colA = newA
```